# Why was CVE-2022-20411 (Bluetooth Remote Code Execution) not detected by Android's BoundSanitizer?

Tags: android, exploit, vulnerability, bluetooth

[CVE-2022-20411](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2022-20411) enabled remote code execution over Bluetooth on Android. It was [fixed in December 2022](https://source.android.com/docs/security/bulletin/2022-12-01?hl=en). But why was it not detected by Android's [BoundsSanitizer](https://source.android.com/docs/security/test/bounds-sanitizer?hl=en)?
Its purpose is to detect and prevent Out of Bounds array accesses and it is deployed "in Bluetooth and codecs.".

So basically it failed in every regard. How? Why?

Comment: I think [CVE-2020-27024](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2020-27024) may be interesting since it's also about out-of-bounds read, but also noted that "*Bounds Sanitizer mitigates this in the default configuration.*"

Comment: @AndrewT. interesting, indeed! But this confuses me even more. If the BoundsSanitizer mitigates the vulnerability, doesn't that mean that the vulnerability should be, well, mitigated? So why does it exist?

Comment: What I understood from the Android Documentation is that Bounds Sanitizer can be configured on or off when building the ROM. So I think the CVE is for general info, especially for ROM makers who disable the check for whatever reason.

Comment: @AndrewT. that makes sense. I forgot that every manufacturer builds the code themselves. But still, if the BoundSanitizer found the issue, couldn't Google have fixed it before publishing it?